# Cannot get Polly to work with Collapse Request

Tags: c#, caching, polly

Im really struggling with Polly

I have the following package references running in a .NET Core Web Api Application

```
<PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="7.2.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Polly.Caching.Distributed" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Polly.Caching.Memory" Version="3.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Polly.Contrib.DuplicateRequestCollapser" Version="0.2.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Polly.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.0" />
```

My task is to use Polly to "Squash multiple requests into a single request"

For this I am trying to use

https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Polly.Contrib.DuplicateRequestCollapser

As a starting point I used

[https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2018/11/caching-in-polly-6-and-the-httpclientfactory/#:~:text=Polly%20allows%20you%20to%20cache,you%20define%20polices%20in%20startup](https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2018/11/caching-in-polly-6-and-the-httpclientfactory/#:%7E:text=Polly%20allows%20you%20to%20cache,you%20define%20polices%20in%20startup).

This gave me a startup of

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Polly;
using Polly.Caching;
using Polly.Caching.Memory;
using Polly.Registry;

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddSingleton<IAsyncCacheProvider, MemoryCacheProvider>();

        IPolicyRegistry<string> registry = services.AddPolicyRegistry();

        services.AddHttpClient("RemoteServer", client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000/api/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        }).AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry(PolicySelector);

        //services.AddSingleton<IRequestService, RequestService>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    private IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> PolicySelector(IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry<string> policyRegistry,
        HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage)
    {
        // you could have some logic to select the right policy
        // see https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2018/07/polly-httpclientfactory-and-the-policy-registry-choosing-the-right-policy-based-on-the-http-request/
        return policyRegistry.Get<IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>>("CachingPolicy");
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IAsyncCacheProvider cacheProvider, IPolicyRegistry<string> registry)
    {
        CachePolicy<HttpResponseMessage> cachePolicy = Policy.CacheAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(cacheProvider, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        registry.Add("CachingPolicy", cachePolicy);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

The sample works but as soon as I add the DuplicateRequestCollapser to the project

I had a compilation error on

```
CachePolicy<HttpResponseMessage> cachePolicy = Policy.CacheAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(cacheProvider, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

That was easy to fix I changed to

```
AsyncCachePolicy<HttpResponseMessage> cachePolicy = Policy.CacheAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(cacheProvider, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

Now when I run I get the error

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'TryGet' in type 'Polly.Caching.Memory.MemoryCacheProvider' from 
assembly 'Polly.Caching.Memory, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8a3ffc3f8f825cc' 
does not have an implementation.'
```

Its tough trying to find clear tutorials for Poly, especially the duplicate request collapser

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

This is not working just from adding the package and I havent even started on integrating the duplicate request collapser itself!  The documentation is not easy to follow

Paul

Comment: Could you please list all of the polly related nuget packages that are in use?

Comment: I have added the packages to the description

Comment: I would assume that you are also using `Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly` because `AddPolicyRegistry` and `AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry` are defined there. Am I right?

Comment: No Im not its just the ones I have listed I can try adding that instead? Maybe it comes in as part of .NET Core 3.1? I have adding the using section to the description

Comment: Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyservicecollectionextensions.addpolicyregistry?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) they are defined there. (I've tried to your in a .NET 3.1 WebApi)

Comment: Yep thats there :)  Im wondering if this is impossible to do - i.e. a package compatibility issue.  I wanted to use that package because it deals nicely with parallel requests

Comment: What sort of package compatibility issue are you talking about? `Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly` does have [versions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly/2.1.0) which are compatible with .NET Core 2.x. Or maybe I understand something. What .NET Core version are using? (I assume 2.1 based on the compatibility setting)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230576/discussion-between-paul-and-peter-csala).

Answer (score 2):

As it turned out that the root cause was the usage of an older version of the package.

Even though it was stated that the 3.0.2 version has been used

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Polly.Caching.Memory" Version="3.0.2" />
```

The error itself tells that the 2.0.0 was in use

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'TryGet' in type 'Polly.Caching.Memory.MemoryCacheProvider' from
> assembly 'Polly.Caching.Memory, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8a3ffc3f8f825cc'
> does not have an implementation.'

After upgrading to 3.0.2 the exception has been gone.

---

Even though most of the packages require 7.1.1 or greater Polly version
the [Polly.Contrib.DuplicateRequestCollapser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly.Contrib.DuplicateRequestCollapser/0.2.1) has a quite strict dependency requirement:

> Polly (>= 7.2.0 && < 8.0.0)

At the time of writing there are only two Polly verions which suffice this requirement: 7.2.0 and 7.2.1

---

So, the moral of this fable is that package versions should be double checked.